# Madhav-Gregory series and Rudimentary Calculation of PI

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, pi, trigonometric-integrals

I have an equation for the value of PI from the Madhava-Gregory series (but with an ability to make it converge faster). It is quite an obvious equation. But I couldn't find these algorithms on the internet.

There are 2 of them one is the Madhava-Gregory series itself (modified):

$${\pi} = {K} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( -1 \right)^{n} {(\tan {\pi \over K})^{2n + 1}}}}{{2n + 1}}} \quad \small{(\text{where}\: K \ge 4)}$$

Here we have to calculate the value K and T (ie. $\tan {\pi \over K}$) externally. They are interlinked constants and are calculated by an algorithm which, (for the lack of a better word) I call TAN-DIP. The whole algorithm looks like this:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
            & \small{\text{Start TAN-DIP iteration with initial value of 1/2}} \nonumber\\
            &\nonumber\\
            v_1 &= ({1 \over 2}) \nonumber\\
            v_2 &= \sqrt{{1 + v_1} \over 2} \nonumber\\
                v_3 &= \sqrt{{1 + v_2} \over 2} \nonumber\\
                &. \nonumber\\
                &. \nonumber\\
                &. \nonumber\\
                v_{R} &= \sqrt{{1 + v_{R-1}} \over 2} \label{ref19}\\
            &\nonumber\\
            &\small{\text{After the TAN-DIP iterations, get the value of tan}} \nonumber\\
            &\nonumber\\
            T &= \sqrt {{1 - v_{R}} \over {1 + v_{R}}} \label{ref20}\\
            &\nonumber\\
            &\small{\text{Determine K}} \nonumber\\
            \nonumber\\
            K &= 3 \times 2^{R+1} \label{ref21}\\
            &\nonumber\\
            &\small{\text{Use K and T in the series and run L iterations}} \nonumber\\
            &\nonumber\\
            {P} &= {K} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^L {\frac{{\left( -1 \right)^{n} {(T)^{2n + 1}}}}{{2n + 1}}} \label{ref22}\\
\end{alignat*}

The second is a very basic one - without any geometry etc. In the algorithm above Just start from 0.5 *(or your choice of $cos({\pi \over x})$ value $x \ge 4$; you may have to change the $K$ equation)* and do just a very high TAN-DIP iteration with very high precision. Ideally it is infinite TAN-DIP with infinite precision. And then just multiply T with K to get PI.

I have made a quick video - sorry a bit monotonus and long.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1mRnbQUfH8

And I have written a self-published paper (non-academic style) available on the internet.
https://eplogica.com/teplics/mgl-series/icmgl-01/

It will take a lot of effort for me to explore it beyond this. But if you are good at numbers, trigonometry, calculus etc., it would be nice if you can make some comments. However, it would be nice to have your thoughts as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry I had mistyped the heading, I have fixed it

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Requiring readers to go off-site and watch a ("monotonous and long") video or read a paper to know what you're even talking about won't get the best reception. Please at least include your equations in the body of your question. (Congratulations on your discovery. If it happens to be known, that won't diminish your accomplishment.)

Comment: Thanks will do the same

Comment: JoséCarlosSantos and @Blue Thanks for you quick response. I have fixed my mistakes and updated the post. I am hoping this will suffice.